# word wrap, word break not working with display flex in firefox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a content `div` whose text can be of any size. My intention is that the content not to overflow from the `div`.It should automatically wrap depending upon the container width. I need `word-break:break-word` property to work in order to achieve my task. Firefox automatically adds a property named `overflow-wrap`, But seems that its not working in firefox with `flex` property. If you remove the flex property you can see it working properly. Is there is any workaround for this without adding an extra `DOM`. Refer my code below

```css
.wrap{
   width:140px;
   height:auto;
   display:flex;
   border:1px solid red;
   height:35px;
   word-wrap:break-word;
   word-break:break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  checkwheatherithasbeenwrapped
</div>
```

Fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/vh1mjr02/).

Please mention only css fix

Answer (score 5):

You can use `word-break: break-all`

```css
.wrap {
  width: 140px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 35px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  checkwheatherithasbeenwrapped
</div>
```

Comment: I want word-wrap :break-word property to work @nenad

Comment: Is this a joke? break-all is not even recognized by firefox.

Answer (score -1):

Try this css

```
-ms-word-break: break-all;
   word-break: break-all;
```